# Locate an edge in the array of edges

Tags: c, algorithm

Suppose I have a struct named Edge representing the edges of a graph.This struct is constructed like this:

```
struct Edge 
{ 
    int src, dest, weight,type; 
};
```

where `edge[x].src` gives the starting point of an edge *x* and `edge[x].dest` the destination.

Let's suppose also that **each combination** of (source,destination) is **unique**.

If I have the destination and source of an edge is there a way to find which edge these two belong to without having to check the whole array `edge[]`?

The edges are initialized like this:

```
edge[0].src = 0; 
edge[0].dest = 1; 
edge[0].weight = 10;

edge[1].src = 0; 
edge[1].dest = 2; 
edge[1].weight = 6;
```

For example if i have *edge[x].dest*=1` and *edge[x].src*=0 ,how can i find x?

Comment: There's no magic here. You either have to check the whole "matrix", or have a secondary data structure.

Comment: You could sort the whole array by the (src, dest) pair after initialization if there are no changes afterwards. Then you can do a binary search to find the edge for a particular (src, dest) pair, if it exists. If you need to preserve the edge numbers used to initialize the array, you could add a member to `struct Edge` to store the edge number.

Comment: You have not provided enough detail on your data structures.  How is the info on nodes structured? If each of the node-info structs has a list of leaving/arriving edges, then your goal is quite easily achieved. If not, you could structure your data accordingly. If the graph is not dynamic (or so little dynmaic that it still makes sense) then you can maintain this kind of info in more than one place. Or you could use more complex references.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I think you don't need the whole information to give an advice.  As it has been suggested in the responses.

Comment: @LuisColorado I disagree. All answers start with or contain "if" or "maybe". More details would reduce guessing, improve the useability of the answers and might (actually I am sure) allow more efficient and/or elegant solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have limited possible values of *src* and *dest*  you can have the additional vector *indexEdge* where `indexEdge[src * N + dest]` values the corresponding index in *edge*

You have to set *indexEdge* when you create a new entry in *edge* and update it if you change an edge src/dest

Comment: Alternatively; `std::unordered_map<std::pair<int,int>,int>` where the key is `{src,dest}`, and the value is `x`. In both my case and yours: make sure that `src`<`dest`.

Comment: @MooingDuck the language is C, not C++ :-)

Comment: There's C hashmap libraries about, I'm sure.

Comment: @MooingDuck all depends on the range of src & dest, if they are large sure a vector with a lot of holes is not a good solution, after in the worst case it is possible to implement a map or any other way to have a search faster than O(n) for sure

Comment: @bruno, by that reason Mooing Duck is suggesting a hash table.... because a large vector full of holes is not desirable... Do you know what a hash table (or a treemap) is?

Comment: @LuisColorado yes I know all of that, it is strange because it is like you don't read my previous answer to MooingDuck. Where is the misunderstanding ?

Comment: @bruno, don't know what answer you refer to.  Are you referring to an answer, or to a comment?

Comment: @LuisColorado I refer "all depends on the range of src & dest, if they are large sure a vector with a lot of holes is not a good solution, after in the worst case it is possible to implement a map or any other way to have a search faster than O(n) for sure"

Comment: Ok, that's completely the contents of the answer given by maxi1985798, but he allows for a two dimensional array, to do the exact thing you propose in your solution (just adding more complexity to the problem)  Read my comment to that answer, and think twice, as normally the graph is an electronic path router or a country map of roads.... the order of the number of the edges is around the ones I put there.

Comment: @LuisColorado I think we say the same thing in fact. A map / treemap / hashmap / ... use more space than a simple vector because of their internal structure when the number of elements/entries is close. So of course the choice of the solution depends on the case, none of them is the best in all case, and the used memory size is not the alone topic to consider.

Comment: No... we are not saying the same thing... indeed you still defend that the plain array is better than the hash/tree map because it consumes less memory per cell.  The maps use as many nodes/cells as arcs are in your graph.... the array uses as many as **possible** arcs you can have in a graph.  You **never** have a fully populated graph in real world.

Comment: @LuisColorado my proposal is _general_,  just a way to transform the search from two keys on a simple access to a vector under the condition this is _reasonable_, that's all, nothing dedicated to a graph.  It is the responsibility of guy to check if that solution is good or not for him, I cannot know that for him.

Comment: Mine is also general.... :)  but as is say in a comment elsewhere, if you have 1.0E6 nodes and 1.0E6 edges  your _general_ approach will lead to 1.0E12 cells vector, and being this case the most common (in any real world application) you'll end discovering that your solution is not _so general_.  We can be discussing months about this... there's no sense in continuing this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with a second data structure like this one. Here matrix has N*N cells, where each cell has the "edge id" what you want.

```
int matrix[MAX_NODES][MAX_NODES];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

/* matrix initialization */
for(i=0; i<MAX_NODES; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<MAX_NODES; i++) {
        matrix[i][j] = -1;
    }
}

/* edge id assing */
for(k=0; k<MAXIMUM_EDGES; i++) {
    matrix[edge[k].src][edge[k].dest] = k;
}

/* now you can get weight from matrix */
printf("edge id for src 0 and dest 1 is %d \n",matrix[0][1]);
```

Comment: Have you considered that the graph can be 1,000,000 (only) nodes and the number of arcs around 1,000,000 (only again) (the same as the number of nodes) and that you are reserved 1,000,000,000,000(ouch!!!) array cells to store the arcs?  (which is 1,000,000 times larger than the needed amount)

Comment: @LuisColorado Thanks a lot!!! your solution with a hashmap is better. i didnt think in memory terms. This is my first time in stackoverflow. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you have the requirement of having edges to be unique (so the graph is not directed) then there's a simple solution:

- generate a key with the ordered pair `{src, dst}` (any kind of order that for each pair of `{src, dst}` tuples gives a single, unique key) and then store them in some kind of hash table (based on the hash to the key) or ordered map.
- in case you can allow `{i,j}` and `{j,i}` keys as valid (a directed graph), then don't sort the indexes on generating the key, so for each pair of nodes you have two possible arcs.  But this is out of scope, as per your requirement (or at least is what I understand from your words).

This will allow you to search the map with the requested key and will not lead to a linear search.  It has also the advantage that for a non-dense graph (only a few pairs of nodes are connected) it consumes less memory storage.

For a non-directed graph, the maximum number of such arcs is `N*(N+1)/2` if it allows self connections, and `N*(N-1)/2` if it doesn't. And for a directed graph the maximum number is `N^2`, so if the graph is not densely populated, an alternative as a hashmap or treemap is desirable.  Hashmaps have `O(1)` access time, and treemaps are `O(log(n))` in which `n` is the total number of arcs in the graph.

The actual implementation of the hash table (or treemap) is left as an exercise, or can be searched for an implementation easily, that fits this specification.